# How to aggregate values in a column between values of another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I want to combine. They look as follows:

```html
df_1
unit   start_time   stop_time
A        0.0          1.2
B        1.3          4.1
A        4.2          4.5
B        4.6          7.2
A        7.3          8.0
```

```html
df_2
time    other_data
0.2       .0122
0.4       .0128
0.6       .0101
0.8       .0091
1.0       .2122
1.2       .1542
1.4       .1546
1.6       .1522
1.8       .2542
2.0       .1557
2.2       .2542
2.4       .1543
2.6       .0121
2.8       .0111
3.0       .0412
3.2       .0214
3.4       .0155
3.6       .0159
3.8       .0154
4.0       .0155
4.2       .0211
4.4       .0265
4.6       .0146
4.8       .0112
5.0       .0166
5.2       .0101
5.4       .0132
5.6       .0112
5.8       .0121
6.0       .0142
6.2       .0124
6.4       .0111
6.6       .0123
6.8       .0111
6.0       .0119
6.2       .0112
6.4       .0131
6.6       .0117
6.8       .0172
7.0       .0123
7.2       .0127
7.4       .0121
7.6       .0110
7.8       .0120
8.0       .0121
```

I want to merge these data frames using the following criteria:

#### Step 1

I want to group all values from df_2.other_data where df_2.time is between df_1.start_time and df_1.stop_time. For example, for the first row of df_1, the following data from df_2 would be grouped:

```
time    other_data
0.2       .0122
0.4       .0128
0.6       .0101
0.8       .0091
1.0       .2122
1.2       .1542
```

#### Step 2

Within this group, I want to count the total number of observations where df_2.other_data is above a threshold, which in this case will be set to .0120. The total number of observations in this group above this threshold is 4. This is the value I want to merge onto df_1. The result should look like this:

```html
unit   start_time   stop_time   other_data_above_threshold
A        0.0          1.2             4
```

The final dataframe should look like this:

```html
unit   start_time   stop_time   other_data_above_threshold
A        0.0          1.2              4
B        1.3          4.1              13
A        4.2          4.5              3
B        4.6          7.2              11
A        7.3          8.0              4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this is what you need.

```
df['other_data_at'] = df.apply(lambda x: df2.loc[(df2['time']>= x['start_time']) & (df2['time']<= x['stop_time'])].loc[df2['other_data']>=0.012].count()[0], axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
   unit start_time  stop_time   other_data_at
0   A   0.0              1.2    4
1   B   1.3              4.1    13
2   A   4.2              4.5    2 #you expected output shows 3 but it should be 2
3   B   4.6              7.2    11
4   A   7.3              8.0    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I would try to loop over your df1 and use it's values for df2

That would look a little like this:

```
def my_counting(df1, df2, threshold):
  count_list = ()
  for index,unit in enumerate(df['unit']):
    df = df2[(df2['time'] >= df1['start_time'][index]) & (df2['time'] < df1['stop_time'][index])]
    count_list.append(df[df['other_data'] <= threshold].shape[0])

  df1['other_data_above_threshold'] = count_list
  return df1

print(my_counting(df1, df2, 0.012)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try use `pd.cut`

```
a = df_1.start_time.to_list() + [np.inf]
s = pd.cut(df_2.time, bins=a, labels=df_1.index, right=False)
df_1['other_data_above_threshold'] = df_2.other_data.gt(0.012).groupby(s).sum()

Out[213]:
  unit  start_time  stop_time  other_data_above_threshold
0    A         0.0        1.2                         4.0
1    B         1.3        4.1                        13.0
2    A         4.2        4.5                         2.0
3    B         4.6        7.2                        11.0
4    A         7.3        8.0                         2.0
```